# libgdx, render shapes using Mesh and ShaderProgram

Tags: java, android, libgdx, shader, mesh

I just started using libgdx and want to render some 2D shapes using a Mesh and a custom ShaderProgram.
I'm experienced in OpenGL, but I don't see my mistake here, maybe someone can help me.

The shader is very basic, vertex:

```
attribute vec2 v;

uniform mat4 o;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(o*vec3(v, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

fragment:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediumhp float;
#endif

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

The mesh (quad 100x100px):

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 6, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 2, "v"));
mesh.setVertices(new float[]{0, 0,
                             100, 0,
                             0, 100,
                             100, 100});
mesh.setIndices(new short[]{0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2});
```

The render stage:

```
Matrix4 o = new Matrix4(); // also tried OrthographicCamera and SpriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix() here...
o.setToOrtho2D(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

shader.begin();
shader.setUniformMatrix(shader.getUniformLocation("o"), o);
mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
shader.end();
```

And thats it. I get no output at all, black screen.
Of course I clear the screen and everything, SpriteBatch (which I also use for different purposes) just works fine. But I don't get how this is done in libgdx or whats wrong here...

Comment: `matrix4.setToOrtho2D` puts the camera at (0,0,0). But when you cast your vertex position to a 3D vector with `vec3(v, 1.0)` you are setting its Z position to 1 so you are effectively putting the mesh behind the camera where it can't be seen. By the way, your fragment shader has a typo for `mediump`.

Comment: Thank you I now switched to render two triangles, which also works of course and is much easier.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So what fixed the black screen?

Comment: Don't set the Z of `gl_Position` to a positive value.

Comment: This post is two years old.